# Ender 3 v2 won't read or recognize any SD cards

Tags: creality-ender-3, microsd

I've just received my Ender 3v2 and tried multiple SD cards, all have been formatted to FAT32 with no luck. Under the Print selection, all I get is the back button. I looked and I have the V4.2.2 and the firmware is up to date, Showing 1.0.2 unless this is not right and this is why I'm having this issue. Even when plugging directly into the computer, nothing is showing up.

Comment: Format them as FAT16. How big is the card?

Comment: Pretty sure FAT32 works fine. Only exfat or whatever latest junk MS is pushing is a problem. This sounds more like a hardware problem.

Comment: We assume your SD card matches the reader as far as HD, xD, etc.  SD cards that are too large can be a problem.

Comment: 1.0.2 is Creality's unique version/branch of Marlin that they've created. It's a branch of Marlin 2.0 so that is totally fine and compatible with a 4.2.2 board. If you've ruled out cards, it may well be the reader. Can you use something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07ZHNGM3G/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_1C5QNXWB7S0AWE057EZS?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1) to test if you can load files from SD cards using the USB port instead of the reader?

Comment: The most recent card is 16gb but I also tried 8gb. And it is a miroSDHC I have not tried using anything to read through the usb port. I'll try that as soon as I can. I'm hoping it's not a hardware problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I ended up reaching out to Creality directly to see if they can help me.

Comment: Have you powercycled?

Comment: Have you tried the card that came with your printer?  Should be a blue 8 GB "emtec" or something similar in name

Answer (score 2):

Abd to follow along with J Boughtons advice, I've noticed if the word "end" is in the first file, it won't read any of the files.

Answer (score 1):

What helps for me is **re-inserting the TF card** several times. Indeed, the machine has some trouble reading it, strange because this would seem to be an easy problem compared to the overall design of the printer....

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure - you know that the SD Card reader in an Ender 3 is upside down?  That means the visible contacts on the micro-SD card have to be facing upward.

If someone has forced a card in the wrong-way around, it could have damaged the reader.

Personally, once I got OctoPrint working I never print from microSD card at all.  Not a solution but a workaround.

Comment: Oddly, the original version had it right, then for some reason they swapped the orientation of the electronics box on later units.

Comment: It was to get the slot away from the table and thus better accessible. This mandated putting all tall components on the one side and flipping the board to be mounted on the ceiling - the tall components facing down. This also simplifies access to the board, no longer you need to remove the top lid awkwardly but access all from below

Comment: @Trish: That's hardly simplifying. It requires you to move the printer, possibly knocking things out of alignment, and turn it upside down to get any access. With the original one you can work on it in-place, even while powered up (not recommended for anything more involved than swapping fans in JST ports or similar).

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Indeed, it made maintenance in there a **hell** but the access panel at last is easier to be accessible... you can actually reach the screw and not work around the heated... once you have the machine upside down or on the side.

Comment: @Trish: Yeah. On mine you can reach the back screw with the short end of a hex wrench, or a right angle screwdriver adapter, but it's a pain. I just keep that one off, since the front two are plenty to hold the panel on.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but whilst none of these worked for me they have worked for other people:

- Make sure the name of the G-code file begins with a letter or number
- Make sure the G-code is not in a subfolder
- Make sure the name of the G-code file is less than or equal to 8 characters long

After I attempted all of these, reinserting the SD card multiple times worked but I don't know what fixed it or if it was just I had been putting it in wrong though I didn't try anything different.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not overlook the possibility of the card not being formatted properly** like I did. Make sure it is FAT32 or another supported format.